# Kotlin SAM to Lambda conversion not working

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my initial callback:

```
geoFirestore.getAtLocation(initialLocation!!, 2.0, object : GeoFirestore.SingleGeoQueryDataEventCallback{
    override fun onComplete(documentSnapshots: List<DocumentSnapshot>?, exception: Exception?) {

    }
})
```

when I convert to lambda I get an error:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: geoFirestore.getAtLocation(initialLocation!!, 2.0) { docs, exception ->
    
}

Comment: Still not working: https://i.imgur.com/N2SRaJi.png @Raghunandan

Comment: Where is `SingleGeoQueryDataEventCallback` defined? If it's in Kotlin, then converting SAM to lambda is not possible. Kotlin only allows converting Java SAMs to lambdas.

Comment: Yes I believe it's Kotlin - that would explain why.

Comment: @Mousa is right! https://readyset.build/kotlins-sam-problem-f315ffe6be3a